# Using Tree Grid to display XML data

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I have an XML data to be displayed in Tree grid. Based on the code sample and learning, I have designed few classes and tried to display it on Tree Grid but nothing comes out on the screen.

The following is the sample XML data

```
<configadmin>
   <service id="service1">
      <property name="minutes" type="STRING" value="120"/>
      <property name="seconds" type="STRING" value="60"/>
      <property name="hours" type="STRING" value="1"/>
   </service>
   <service id="service2">
         <property name="host" type="STRING" value="localhost"/>
         <property name="port" type="STRING" value="8080"/>
   </service>
</configadmin>
```

```
  public class ConfigId {

   private String id;
   private List<ConfigProperty> configProperty = new ArrayList<>();

   public ConfigId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   /**
    * @return the id
    */
   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   /**
    * @param id the id to set
    */
   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }


   /**
    * @return the configProperty
    */
   public List<ConfigProperty> getConfigProperty() {
      return configProperty;
   }

   /**
    * @param configProperty the configProperty to set
    */
   public void setConfigProperty(List<ConfigProperty> configProperty) {
      this.configProperty = configProperty;
   }

   /**
    * @param configProperty the configProperty to add
    */
   public void addConfigProperty(ConfigProperty configProperty) {
      this.configProperty.add(configProperty);
   }

}

public class ConfigProperty{

   private String name;
   private String type;
   private String value;

   public ConfigProperty(String name, String type, String value) {
      this.name = name;
      this.type = type;
      this.value = value;
   }

   /**
    * @return the name
    */
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   /**
    * @param name the name to set
    */
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   /**
    * @return the type
    */
   public String getType() {
      return type;
   }

   /**
    * @param type the type to set
    */
   public void setType(String type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   /**
    * @return the value
    */
   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   /**
    * @param value the value to set
    */
   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

}

UI Code

      gridLayout.setSizeUndefined();
      gridLayout.setSpacing(true);
      Panel panel = new Panel("Configuration Settings");
      panel.setWidth("130px");
      TreeGrid serviceGrid = new TreeGrid();
      List<ConfigId> serviceList = xmlConfigDomParser.getServicesList();
      serviceGrid.setItems(serviceList);
      gridLayout.addComponent(panel, 0, 0);
      gridLayout.addComponent(button, 2, 0);
      gridLayout.addComponent(serviceGrid, 0, 2);
```

I am trying to solve the following scenario,

On clicking the Service ID, all the properties need to be displayed and only the values needs to be edited.

At first I am not able to display the data on the Tree Grid, please advise.

```
Service Id, Name, Type, Value
service1
        minutes, STRING, 120
        seconds, STRING, 60
        hours, STRING, 1
service2
        host, STRING, localhost
        port, STRING, 8080
```

Comment: Seems like you haven't added any columns to your tree grid :) You can look into the addColumn methods, or use the `new TreeGrid(ConfigId.class);` to generate them automatically.

Comment: I updated the code and now I could atleast get some display even though results are not as expected.
```
TreeGrid serviceGrid = new TreeGrid(ConfigId.class);



I was getting the results like the below,
ConfigProperty                         Id
                                     calibration.instance.storage      
[config.util.ConfigProperty@2b93bdff,
config.util.ConfigProperty@3340c66d,
config.util.ConfigProperty@67d10831,
config.util.ConfigProperty@22ceb311]
```

Comment: If nothing else is defined, it will use `toString()` methods to show the data. So it shows the Id and the list of ConfigProperties.

Do you want to show both ConfigIds and ConfigProperties in the TreeGrid? If so they need a common superclass, you can not have two different classes in the same grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working now